# Error while compiling software in centos?

Tags: linux, centos, centos6

/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_ParserCreate'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to`XML_GetErrorCode'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetUserData'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to`XML_ErrorString'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetEntityDeclHandler'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to`XML_ParserFree'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_SetElementHandler'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to`XML_StopParser'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to `XML_Parse'
/usr/local/apr/lib/libaprutil-1.so: undefined reference to`XML_SetCharacterDataHandler'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [htpasswd] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/root/httpd-2.4.38/support'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/root/httpd-2.4.38/support'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: don't you think that puttng kernel tags here is a bit misleading?

Comment: I would also add that compiling as root is probably not a good idea. That said, What are you trying to achieve? you don't even name the software you are trying to compile....

Comment: first of all, why are you compiling httpd instead of using the one packaged in centos?